# Importing data into Fedora Commons

Tags: import, fedora-commons

I've just set up Fedora Commons on a webserver, and now I want to import 5 GB of XML files into it.  Is there a way to do this without having to go through the web interface, eg. Some directory I can just copy the files into after performing some operation to make them readable by Fedora Commons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to

**fedora Home Folder** - > **client** - > **bin** - > **fedora-admin.sh or fedora-admin.bat**

run it, it will ask you for fedora port(8080) and password(fedoraAdmin) etc.

[image: Fedora Login]

go to **File** menu - > **Ingest** - > **Multiple Objects** - > **From Directory**

[image: fedora directory import]

Answer (score 0):

Is the XML data new content you want to ingest or FOXML content you are importing from another Fedora Commons server?

Answer (score 0):

Fedora has a [batch import function available](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/FEDORA36/Fedora+Administrator#FedoraAdministrator-IngestMultipleObjects) from its Java GUI, which you can start from the command line:

`$FEDORA_HOME/client/bin/fedora-admin.sh` (or `fedora-admin.bat` if you're on Windows).

You need to generate FOXML or METS XML files for the objects you want to ingest however, so XSLT may be in order.